# Error import csv in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm following this [guide](https://linkurio.us/blog/how-to-use-phone-calls-and-network-analysis-to-identify-criminals/) to create a graph dataset. Now I have to import a CSV file in Neo4j. To do this I'm using this [script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jvilledieu/2dc83327b5de17f0988e/raw/ec257127028ec0aa592235016c5047c00eb5fc6b/Call_records_data_import) where I have edited only the paths to the CSV file.

When I execute it in Neo4j shell I get this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'R': expected 'e/E' 
(line 23, column 2 (offset: 1116))
"DROP CONSTRAINT ON (a:PERSON) ASSERT a.number IS UNIQUE;"
```

Also, these lines are underlined with error:

> extraneous input

```
ON CREATE SET a.first_name = line.FIRST_NAME, a.last_name = line.LAST_NAME, 
a.full_name = line.FULL_NAME
ON MATCH SET a.first_name = line.FIRST_NAME, a.last_name = line.LAST_NAME, 
a.full_name = line.FULL_NAME
...
ON CREATE SET c.start = toInt(line.START_DATE), c.end= toInt(line.END_DATE), 
c.duration = line.DURATION
MERGE (d:LOCATION {cell_tower: line.CELL_TOWER})
ON CREATE SET d.address= line.ADDRESS, d.state = line.STATE, d.city = 
line.CITY
...
```

Instead, this line gets this error message:

> Missing ';' at DROP

```
DROP CONSTRAINT ON (a:PERSON) ASSERT a.number IS UNIQUE;
```

Comment: Rather than repeating the same things in ON CREATE SET and ON MATCH SET, just use these for properties that are specifically in one or the other, not both. Then use a normal SET for properties that you want set in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Adding ID field in dataset
2. rename field "cell_site" in "cell_tower" in dataset
3. Open .conf file and allow to load file from everywhere
4. execute istructions in block, not in the same command.

Comment: Is this the step-by-step procedure you followed to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should put your CSV file in the Neoj4 import directory. If you are using a Windows desktop community edition version, this directory is `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\import` (see [file location docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations)).

Then change your `LOAD CSV` statement to:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///call_records_dummy.csv" AS line
```

Comment: In windows i can't find this file. I've neo4j dekstop v1.1
in linux i edited conf file to load file from everywhere but i've same errors

Comment: stupid question: can i insert all istructions in one shot o do i have to insert one instruction per time?